# jQuery Dialog : Not to open it if it's already opened?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

i am opening jQuery Dialog through the below code.The problem here is when i opened it and click again so its still opening second and third time.

i need to open it just one time if it's not already open.

```
        $('.view_full_email').live('click',function(){
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var subject = $tr.children('td:eq(2)').text(),
        from = $tr.children('td:eq(3)').text(),
        to = $tr.children('td:eq(4)').text(),
        cc = $tr.children('td:eq(5)').text(),
        bcc = $tr.children('td:eq(6)').text(),
        mesg_body = $tr.children('td:eq(7)').text();

      var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Email'}).dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           resizable: true,
           width: 500
       });
      var email_data = "<table><tr><td><b>Subject :</b>"+ subject +"</td></tr><br/><tr><td><b>From :</b> "+ from +"</td></tr><tr><td><b>To :</b> "+ to+"</td></tr><tr><td><b>CC  :</b> "+ cc+"</td></tr><tr><td><b>BCC  : </b> "+ bcc+"</td></tr><tr><td><b> Message Body :</b> <textarea rows='25' cols='100' readonly = 'readonly'>"  + mesg_body+ "</textarea></td></tr></table>";
       $('<div>').html(email_data).appendTo($dialog);
       $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you do this `modal :true` .

this way user wont click anything in background so no need to put condition because your dialog will open just once. i guess this is what u want

```
var $dialog = $('<div>',{title:'Email'}).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: true,
            modal :true,
            width: 500
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
if (!$dialog.dialog("isOpen")){
    $dialog.dialog("open");    
}
```

Comment: i have a grid with multiple rows in every row there is this link on which the dialog will open.now if i click on one link so it will open the dialog thats fine but when user again click the same link user already clciked so i want that no same dialog is open.hope u got what i am trying to say